# Signature Puzzle

Tags: crosswords

*Sad plotlines have a special place in this constructor's heart.*

[image: Crossword grid]

#### Clues

```
Across
1. Orphan protagonist of "Black Clover"
5. Fuss
8. Recipe amt.
11. Income source for a YouTuber, perhaps
14. Like newly made clothing
16. Discarded bits from juicing
18. Part before :00, say
19. Capital bordering the Persian Gulf
21. Aggressively intense
22. Ctrl+Y or Shift+Ctrl+Z, in many programs
23. Therefore, to Descartes
24. The "D" of "Nintendo DS", in one interpretation
25. Country bordering the Persian Gulf
26. "Cat on ___ Tin Roof"
28. Series of chat messages or posts
30. Quantum physicist's counterpart to ket
31. Common suffix of three consecutive Greek letters
32. Jack's value in blackjack
33. "Junji ___ Collection" (horror anthology series)
34. Titanium dioxide mineral
37. "The Twits" author
39. Lowered oneself, in a way
41. Swordstick, as perceived by the unsuspecting
42. ___ salts
45. African country north of Ethiopia
47. Devoid (of)
49. Classical Japanese drama
50. Expansion of a common contraction
52. Popular video game scripting language
54. Calculator symbol
56. Elementary particle in physics
58. Expansion ___ (gaming supplement)
59. Asian gambling mecca
61. Chat service superseded by Hangouts, informally
62. Ancient Greek region containing modern day Athens
64. Brother of Moses
66. Model Macpherson, or a magazine she's been on
68. ___ chi (martial art)
69. Recurring small electrical jellyfish enemy in "The Legend of Zelda"
71. Equivalence relation symbol, in mathematics
73. Duck Konundrum puzzle constructor Dan
75. Web initials with HTML and JS
78. Fill-in worker
80. Hued coating substance
82. Like speed but not velocity
86. Titular mouse of a cartoon within a cartoon
88. Juice, so to speak
90. Lunar "sea"
92. Knit shirt, usually
93. Distinctive air
94. Cryptocurrency with the second largest market cap as of May 2018 (abbr.)
95. Cat-like Kana from "Saki"
97. "Little Busters!" girl with a spin-off game, familiarly
98. Gambian currency unit
101. Still longing for more
105. Integer like 19 but not 91
107. Forbidden (var.)
108. Anarchy sister with Stocking, mentored by Garterbelt
109. Crosswordese sword
111. :00
113. Male sheep
114. Sheep sound
115. First word of a pasta dish, or the dish's initials
118. Word of disgust
119. Street racer Fujiwara portrayed by Jay Chou in 2005
122. Microsoft Office : Excel :: LibreOffice : ___
123. 4047 square meters, approximately
125. Follow, as a detective might
127. Country bordering the Persian Gulf
128. Committed perjury, perhaps
130. Cream of ___
132. Active Sicilian volcano
133. Prefix with science or present
134. Gassy drink
135. Herculean
136. "A long time ___ in a galaxy far, far away...."
137. Badger
138. ___ neutrality
139. South Australian salt lake

Down
1. "Angel Beats!" or "Charlotte", say
2. Accumulation from exercising
3. Natural picker-upper?
4. ___ de Triomphe
5. Maid café employee's need, usually
6. "For the First Time in Forever", for one
7. Dated
8. Ripped (up)
9. Coffee mix-in
10. Lettuce, apples, cucumbers, etc.
11. Contribute, to a conversation
12. It lets you go from B to A
13. Internet repost, e.g.
14. Roswell sighting, according to some
15. Below, poetically
17. Beatrix who created Peter Rabbit
18. "___ Story" (2015 police procedural indie game)
20. ___ carte
27. With Saint, place of exile for Napoleon
29. What's in Henry's bucket, per a children's song
33. Numeric data type in programming
35. Feather's partner
36. Not competent
38. "What ___, chopped liver?"
39. Android version between Jellybean and Lollipop
40. Gypsum : 2 :: ___ : 1
42. "Dororon ___-kun", by the creator of "Cutie Honey"
43. Make a sullen expression
44. Bar order in a small glass
46. Almond ___ (chocolatey candy in gold foil)
47. Show reluctance
48. Mexican archeological site and former capital of the Toltec Empire
51. Free (time)
53. Country bordering the Persian Gulf, briefly
55. Kind of resort
57. End of a pen
59. Grinding tooth
60. Lyrics drawn out before "will always love you"
61. C func. for reading a single char
63. Ouagadougou, e.g.
65. Ready for picking
67. Used a light beam on
70. Louvre Pyramid architect
72. Animosity
74. Ray gun sound
75. US parallel of MI6
76. Jewelry bit for an earlobe
77. Marking a surface, in a way
79. Gardening container
81. "___ it easy!"
83. Thor's archenemy in comics
84. Former student, briefly
85. Took a taxi, e.g.
87. Islamic adjective in an Australian kebab meat "snack"
89. Thrash at a game or contest
91. Give out hands again
96. Large primate
99. Blood group letters
100. Drawing force
102. Unintentionally funny dramatic moment, according to TVTropes
103. Escargots, say
104. Right now, in chat
106. Wed again
110. Formal agreements
111. Megumi who voiced Shinji Ikari ("Neon Genesis Evangelion")
112. Running theme in "My Name Is Earl"
114. Not competent in
116. Voice ___
117. Origami beginner's creation
118. Pick-up vehicle, in Australia
120. "The Simpsons" alien, with Kodos
121. Place of tertiary education, colloquially
122. Yield, as territory
124. Work unit
126. ___-Tzu (Chinese philosopher)
129. Na+ or Cl-, say
131. "The dog ___ my homework"
```

#### Across TEXT (for use with [Across Lite](http://www.litsoft.com/across/alite/download/))

```
<ACROSS PUZZLE V2>
<TITLE>
Signature Puzzle
<AUTHOR>
Sp3000
<COPYRIGHT>
2018
<SIZE>
21x21
<GRID>
.XXXX..XXX...XXX.XXX.
XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX..XXX
.XXX.XXX.XXX..XXXXXX.
...XXXX.XXXXX..XXXX..
XXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.
XXX.XXXXX...XXX..XXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX
XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.XXX
...XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX...
XXX.XXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX
XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXX..XXX...XXXXX.XXX
.XXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXX
..XXXX..XXXXX.XXXX...
.XXXXXX..XXX.XXX.XXX.
XXX..XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX
.XXX.XXX...XXX..XXXX.
<ACROSS>
Orphan protagonist of "Black Clover"
Fuss
Recipe amt.
Income source for a YouTuber, perhaps
Like newly made clothing
Discarded bits from juicing
Part before :00, say
Capital bordering the Persian Gulf
Aggressively intense
Ctrl+Y or Shift+Ctrl+Z, in many programs
Therefore, to Descartes
The "D" of "Nintendo DS", in one interpretation
Country bordering the Persian Gulf
"Cat on ___ Tin Roof"
Series of chat messages or posts
Quantum physicist's counterpart to ket
Common suffix of three consecutive Greek letters
Jack's value in blackjack
"Junji ___ Collection" (horror anthology series)
Titanium dioxide mineral
"The Twits" author
Lowered oneself, in a way
Swordstick, as perceived by the unsuspecting
___ salts
African country north of Ethiopia
Devoid (of)
Classical Japanese drama
Expansion of a common contraction
Popular video game scripting language
Calculator symbol
Elementary particle in physics
Expansion ___ (gaming supplement)
Asian gambling mecca
Chat service superseded by Hangouts, informally
Ancient Greek region containing modern day Athens
Brother of Moses
Model Macpherson, or a magazine she's been on
___ chi (martial art)
Recurring small electrical jellyfish enemy in "The Legend of Zelda"
Equivalence relation symbol, in mathematics
Duck Konundrum puzzle constructor Dan
Web initials with HTML and JS
Fill-in worker
Hued coating substance
Like speed but not velocity
Titular mouse of a cartoon within a cartoon
Juice, so to speak
Lunar "sea"
Knit shirt, usually
Distinctive air
Cryptocurrency with the second largest market cap as of May 2018 (abbr.)
Cat-like Kana from "Saki"
"Little Busters!" girl with a spin-off game, familiarly
Gambian currency unit
Still longing for more
Integer like 19 but not 91
Forbidden (var.)
Anarchy sister with Stocking, mentored by Garterbelt
Crosswordese sword
:00
Male sheep
Sheep sound
First word of a pasta dish, or the dish's initials
Word of disgust
Street racer Fujiwara portrayed by Jay Chou in 2005
Microsoft Office : Excel :: LibreOffice : ___
4047 square meters, approximately
Follow, as a detective might
Country bordering the Persian Gulf
Committed perjury, perhaps
Cream of ___
Active Sicilian volcano
Prefix with science or present
Gassy drink
Herculean
"A long time ___ in a galaxy far, far away...."
Badger
___ neutrality
South Australian salt lake
<DOWN>
"Angel Beats!" or "Charlotte", say
Accumulation from exercising
Natural picker-upper?
___ de Triomphe
Maid cafe employee's need, usually
"For the First Time in Forever", for one
Dated
Ripped (up)
Coffee mix-in
Lettuce, apples, cucumbers, etc.
Contribute, to a conversation
It lets you go from B to A
Internet repost, e.g.
Roswell sighting, according to some
Below, poetically
Beatrix who created Peter Rabbit
"___ Story" (2015 police procedural indie game)
___ carte
With Saint, place of exile for Napoleon
What's in Henry's bucket, per a children's song
Numeric data type in programming
Feather's partner
Not competent
"What ___, chopped liver?"
Android version between Jellybean and Lollipop
Gypsum : 2 :: ___ : 1
"Dororon ___-kun", by the creator of "Cutie Honey"
Make a sullen expression
Bar order in a small glass
Almond ___ (chocolatey candy in gold foil)
Show reluctance
Mexican archeological site and former capital of the Toltec Empire
Free (time)
Country bordering the Persian Gulf, briefly
Kind of resort
End of a pen
Grinding tooth
Lyrics drawn out before "will always love you"
C func. for reading a single char
Ouagadougou, e.g.
Ready for picking
Used a light beam on
Louvre Pyramid architect
Animosity
Ray gun sound
US parallel of MI6
Jewelry bit for an earlobe
Marking a surface, in a way
Gardening container
"___ it easy!"
Thor's archenemy in comics
Former student, briefly
Took a taxi, e.g.
Islamic adjective in an Australian kebab meat "snack"
Thrash at a game or contest
Give out hands again
Large primate
Blood group letters
Drawing force
Unintentionally funny dramatic moment, according to TVTropes
Escargots, say
Right now, in chat
Wed again
Formal agreements
Megumi who voiced Shinji Ikari ("Neon Genesis Evangelion")
Running theme in "My Name Is Earl"
Not competent in
Voice ___
Origami beginner's creation
Pick-up vehicle, in Australia
"The Simpsons" alien, with Kodos
Place of tertiary education, colloquially
Yield, as territory
Work unit
___-Tzu (Chinese philosopher)
Na+ or Cl-, say
"The dog ___ my homework"
<NOTEPAD>
Sad plotlines have a special place in this constructor's heart.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is:

> [**SUMMER POCKETS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Pockets), upcoming visual novel

The puzzle is about:

> S.P. phrases (Sp3000, Signature Puzzle, Sad plotlines, special place)

The completed grid is:

> [image: enter]

In that grid, we should note:

> There are thirteen entries beginning with 'S' and thirteen beginning with 'P'. These are the only Ss and Ps in the grid; they are highlighted pink and green above.
>  The S words are: SWEAT, SUGAR, SHARE, SHOT, SPARE, SKI, STUD, SCRATCHING, SCALAR, SUCTION, SNAILS, SODA, STRONG
>  The P words are: PRODUCE, PULP, POTTER, POUT, PACK, PLUS, POT, POWER, PAINT, POLO, PRIME, PANTY, PACTS

To extract a final answer:

> Each of the S words is part of a common S.P. phrase. The P word for that phrase is one letter off from one of the P words in the grid. The clue for the S word and the clue for the corresponding P word both begin with the same letter, running A through M to give an ordering.
>  In the final order, here are the S.P. phrases with the P word from the grid, followed by the letters that differ between the phrase and the grid. (These letters are highlighted blue in the grid above.)
>  (Accumulation.../Anarchy...) SWEAT PANTS/PANTY = S/Y
>  (Bar.../Beatrix...) SHOT PUTTER/POTTER = U/O
>  (Coffee.../Calculator...) SUGAR PLUM/PLUS = M/S
>  (Drawing.../Discarded...) SUCTION PUMP/PULP = M/L
>  (Escargots.../Expansion...) SNAILS PACE/PACK = E/K
>  (Free.../Formal...) SPARE PARTS/PACTS = R/C
>  (Gassy.../Gardening...) SODA POP/POT = P/T
>  (Herculean/Hued...) STRONG POINT/PAINT = O/A
>  (Internet.../Integer...) SHARE PRICE/PRIME = C/M
>  (Jewelry.../Juice...) STUD POKER/POWER = K/W
>  (Kind.../Knit...) SKI POLE/POLO = E/O
>  (Like.../Lettuce...) SCALAR PRODUCT/PRODUCE = T/E
>  (Marking.../Make...) SCRATCHING POST/POUT = S/U
>  Taking the first letters (the letters in the actual phrases) in this order spells out **SUMMER POCKETS**.

Comment: 1.5 hours, including that *detailed* explanation?  R U A robot?